# how to save data to user History

Tags: node.js, express

I have a method that adds orders to a user history, I am trying to use the same logic for a feature that allows users to request a refund, how do I achieve this because I am not having it save.

```
//this is the order object sent from the client-side

order: {
    products: [ [Object] ],
    returns: 30000,
    transaction_id: '965892579',
    amount: 60000
  }

    //This method add order to user history successfully, and it works well and I can also see order save in user history.

    exports.addOrderToUserHistory =(req, res, next)=>{
        let history = []
    
         req.body.order.products.forEach((item)=>{
             history.push({
               _id: item._id,
               name: item.name,
               description: item.description,
               quantity:item.quantity,
               roi:item.roi,
               brand:item.brand,
               //category:item.category,
               duration: item.duration,
               amount: req.body.order.amount,
               returns: req.body.order.returns,
               transaction_id: req.body.order.transaction_id
             })
         })
    
         //Update user history 
         User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:req.profile._id}, 
          {$push: {history:history}},
          {new: true}, 
          (error, data)=>{
          if(error){
            return res.status(400).json({
              error:"Could not be update user purchase history"
            })
          }
         next();
         })
    
    }



  //this is the refund request object sent from the client-side

requestRefund: {
    amount: '3456788',
    transaction_id: '914236683'
  }

/`
```

> ///The method below is suppose to add requested refund data to user request
> history, but am not having it save, I don't know what I did wrong.

`

```
exports.addRequestRefundToUserHistory = (req, res, next)=>{
      
  let refunds= {

    amount: req.body.requestRefund.amount,
    transaction_id: req.body.requestRefund.transaction_id
  }



//Update user Requesthistory 

User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:req.profile._id}, 
 {$push: {refunds:refunds}},
 {new: true}, 
 (error, data)=>{
 if(error){
   return res.status(400).json({
     error:"Could not be update user withdraw history"
   })
 }
next();
})


 }
```